# How to define a nested Pydantic model with a list of tuples containing ints and floats?

Tags: python, swagger, fastapi, pydantic

I have a model output that is a list of tuples of ints and floats, something like this:

Model output:

```py
[(12, 1.323), (3, 0.423), (324, 1.542)...(214, 1.120)]
```

The POST endpoint I've defined creates a dictionary of `{string: model output}` and I can't seem to understand how to define the response schema so that the model output is returned successfully.

The below class will allow me to return the key in the aforementioned dictionary when testing and my best guess is that this what I need to manipulate to get what I'm looking for.

```py
class response_schema(BaseModel):
    response: List[str] = []
```

Comment: If the answer provided below helped you please consider upvoting it and marking it as the answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming your endpoint returns a dict, not an array:

```
from typing import Dict, Tuple

class response_schema(BaseModel):
    response: Dict[str, List[Tuple[int, float]]]
```

Comment: Thanks this is helpful. It ultimately boiled down to some of the data types when building the endpoint and I was actually able to keep the response_schema I defined initially.